# Array loop how to times itself three times

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java, and I am trying to make the below array to make it times itself three times. The output is currently the same. How do I make it so it makes the output: let's say input i=1 and output will be {3,6,12} so it times the number before that three times.

```
double [] conversion = new double [3];
for(int i=0;i<conversion.length;i++){
    conversion[i]=3*bytes;
```

Comment: Where is `bytes` coming from?  And `i` isn't an "input", it's a loop counter that has the values 0, 1 and 2 in turn.  I'm not sure *exactly* what you're trying to do here.  (For example, if you made the `conversion` array 4 elements long, would you expect the fourth element to be 24?)

Comment: What is the variable bytes? Should it not be i?

Comment: replace 'bytes' with 'i'

Answer (score 0):

```
double [] conversion = new double [3];
for(int i=0;i<conversion.length;i++){
    conversion[i]=3*i;
```

But where comes bytes form, why do you use it

Comment: bytes = from the scanner

Comment: @Doris, so you want bytes*3, bytes*6 bytes*9 etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to set the first value in the array to 3x your input, and then just loop through the values after that.

```
int inputNumber = 1;
int[] conversion = new int[3];
conversion[0] = inputNumber * 3;
for(int i = 1; i < conversion.length; i++) {
    conversion[i] = conversion[i-1] * 3;
}
```