# Array loop multiply itself by 1024

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to make an array so that whatever the byte input, the next three answer will multiply itself by 1024. At the moment the inputs are all the same. Grateful if anyone could help

```
public class ExcerciseFour {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String [] UNITS = {"B","KB","MB","GB"};

    double bytes;
    double kilobytes;
    double megabytes;
    double gigabytes;

    System.out.print("Enter in bytes: ");
    bytes = keyboard.nextDouble();
    kilobytes = (bytes/1024);
    megabytes = (bytes/1048576);
    gigabytes = (bytes/1073741824);

//  System.out.println(bytes+"bytes"+" is equivalent to "+kilobytes+(UNITS[1])+", "+megabytes+UNITS[2]+", "+gigabytes+UNITS[3]+".");

    double [] conversion = new double [3];
    for(int i=0;i<conversion.length;i++){
            conversion[i]=bytes/1024;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(conversion));
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array loop how to times itself three times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314246/array-loop-how-to-times-itself-three-times)

Answer (score 0):

They are all the same because you assign to them all `bytes/1024`. Since `bytes` does not change, they should all be the same.

To fix the problem, you could have an auxiliary variable that is divided by 1024 and reassigned to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like

```
 val = bytes
 for(int i=0;i<conversion.length;i++)
 {
        conversion[i]=val;
        val /= 1024
 }
```